Elasticsearch upgrade from 7.17 to latest 8.x version
I have an index on elasticsearch v7.17 and I want to upgrade my cluster to v8. I know remote reindexing is an option but because of my data size I want to avoid it. My elasticsearch deployment is on the Elastic Cloud. It is not self-managed.
I created a custom S3 repository and registered to both my deployments 7.17 and 8.15.
The issue is that any snapshot I create on the 8.15 deployment is visible on both the deployments but then the snapshot created on 7.17 is not visible on the 8.15 deployment.
I tried creating the complete snapshot, including all the indices, global state etc on 7.17, but it was not listing down in the snapshots on 8.15.
So, I tried to create the snapshot only for the index I want to restore say "Index-A" using
PUT _snapshot/<<repo>>/my-snapshot
{
  "indices": "Index-A",
  "include_global_state": false,
  "ignore_unavailable": true
}

Even after this the snapshot did not show up on the 8.15 deployment?
So my question is: Is the snapshot created on 7.17 available to restore on v8.x or is there something else that I am missing?

I figured out the reason for the snapshots not showing up on the 8.x deployment.
The repository I registered was not set to read-only on the 8.x cluster. Once I edited the repository and set it as read-only on the 8.x cluster, all the snapshots started to show up.
Read Only Warning for Repositories

Let's go from simple to more complicated:

You don't really need a snapshot, you could just do a rolling upgrade. Though make sure you've looked at the upgrade assistant in Kibana and resolve all the breaking changes.
If you want to have the peace of mind that you can always easily go back, you could spin up a new cluster from the built-in snapshot in cloud and roll forward from that (this should only require some clicks in the UI).
If the custom snapshots are in the same repository, they should be visible (and you can restore a 7.x snapshot into an 8.x cluster — assuming all indices have been created with 7.0+). What's the output of fetching all snapshots on the 8.x cluster for the shared snapshot repo?


Thanks for the 2nd approach. I will try that out too.
The custom snapshots are in the same repository. When I try to fetch all snapshots on the 8.x cluster I only see those snapshots that were taken on the 8.x cluster.
